# How to have a common class for Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an app which has `Facebook` login functionality. I am using `Facebook` login from two separate screens. One from the welcome screen, which is the entry point of the app. I have some features which is available for Logged in users. So when try to access those features app shows a DialogFragment with login with facebook button, on click of that button same Facebook login api should be called.

I don't want to repeat the code for Facebook, for that reason I want to separate Facebook login to separate class. I cannot have a normal class, as the Facebook login callbacks are dependent on `onActivityResult`. Please help me to separate facebook login to a common class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a normal class with a function:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // do here whatever you want...
}
```

and then, in your activity, call this function from this class instance:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebookClass.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```